# Create object with form-encoded dot-path properties

Tags: laravel, post, dingo-api

In laravel/dingo you may create new objects by POSTing the data either as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or as `application/json`:

```
$ curl -XPOST --data name=foo http://example.org/user
```

JSON:

```
$ curl -XPOST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"name":"foo"}' http://example.org/user
```

Both work fine.

---

What I now want to do is creating objects with nested properties, e.g. `name.first`. This works fine when POSTing JSON:

```
$ curl -XPOST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"name":{"first:"foo"}}' http://example.org/user
```

But it fails when using form-encoded data:

```
$ curl -XPOST --data name.first=foo http://example.org/user
```

The exception is `The name.first field is required`.

---

I know that PHP [converts dots to underscores](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php):

> PHP will automatically replace any dots in incoming variable names with underscores.

This might be the reason laravel does not detect the variables as being nested.

---

How can I make laravel detect the dot paths in variable names correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use

```
$ curl -XPOST --data name%5Bfirst%5D=foo http://example.org/user
```

which is equal to `name['first'] = foo`

:)